# Azure App picking up connection string from machine.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I've deployed an MVC application on MS Azure as an App Service.

It was working fine until the last update, and now the error I am getting is that the application is picking up `connectionString` from `machine.config` rather than the one in `web.config`.

1. I know it is not suggested to edit `machine.config`
2. Even if I want to; I cant change the values as I do not have access to the `machine.config` file.

I've tried adding a `<clear />` at the starting of my `<connectionStrings>` in `web.config` but somehow one part/view of the application works (where I've just used `web.api` to populate page on client side), however when the page/view is being populated using a controller on server side, it throws error (SQL Error: `network related or instance specific error`).

The application is somehow referring to a connection string named `LocalSqlServer`. But, I've not mentioned a connection string with that name in whole application.

The issue with debugging is that, the application works perfectly on local instance however not on the production.

This is how my connection string looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<appSettings>
   <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
   <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
<clear/>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=myservername;initial catalog=mydbname;User ID=userid;Password=password;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="AppDBModel" connectionString="data source=myservername;initial catalog=mydbname;User ID=userid;Password=password;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>


<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <roleManager enabled="true"></roleManager>
  <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="/Error"></customErrors>

</system.web>
<system.webServer>

  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  </modules>

 <handlers>
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
   <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
   <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
 </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
   </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
<!--<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>-->
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="data source=myservername;initial catalog=mydbname;User ID=userid;Password=password;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
   </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

**Adding Error Stack Trace**

I get this when I remove `<clear/>` from the `connectionString` in `web.config`

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +821
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +5782239
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +507
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154

System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +209
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +75

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +125
 System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +89
 System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) +29
 System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +386
```

And this is what I get when I add the `<clear />` tag again.

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Source Error: 
An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 262
```

Comment: What makes you think this is coming from `machine.config`?

Comment: @DavidEbbo, because the error I get from the error screen points out that connection string named `LocalSqlServer` was not found in `machine.config`

Comment: Can you give more details on the error you are getting (e.g. is there a stack?) and the code you are writing that leads to the error? Even if machine.config has this, why is it affecting you? Is your code enumerating and trying all connection strings? It feels there is just too much missing from your question.

Comment: @DavidEbbo, added the stack trace to the question :)

Comment: I took a crack at an answer, but frankly it's not my expertise (I'm on the Azure Web App side of things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to `RoleManager` which was set to `true` however the `defaultProvider` was not provided. Thanks to [@DavidEbbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111888/david-ebbo) for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49470539/1584140).

This made the server pick the same from `machine.config` instead.

Now, as mentioned in my comments, for the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49470539/1584140) that was indeed for `ASP Membership` however the current application uses `ASP Identity` so that did not really work.

In-fact I had to write my own logic to handle `Roles` in the application because making use of the integrated `RoleProvider` was more of a redundancy for the simple login I needed to implement. So as of now, the current application no longer uses the integrated `RoleProvider` but a custom made `RoleProvider`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it relates to you having `<roleManager enabled="true">` in your web.config, but without configuring it. That causes it to use the `MySQLRoleProvider` section from machine.config, which references `connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"`. Instead, you're supposed to configure the role manager with your own DB.

e.g. from [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/membership-and-role-provider), you should have something like this:

```
<roleManager enabled ="true"   
             defaultProvider ="SqlRoleProvider" >  
  <providers>  
    <add name ="SqlRoleProvider"   
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"   
         connectionStringName="SqlConn"   
         applicationName="MembershipAndRoleProviderSample"/>  
  </providers>  
</roleManager>
```

Comment: I think it makes sense.. because the home view has no role check.. but the view that checks the roles is the one that breaks. Not sure if this would work with ASP Identity .. I've used it in ASP Membership though.